# How to make vertical line between 2 articles?

Tags: html, css

Hello Guys I am trying to make a padding in between my 2 articles with a vertical line but every time I try to make it, it just doesn't show the line at all because I set my background of page blue, so how can I bypass my background to set the line to black so it shows over the background. Anyone got an idea?

```css
#artworkArticlesLeft{
 float:left;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 width:60%;
 padding-left:10%;
 padding-right:4%;
 border-left:
 
}

#artworkArticlesRight{
 padding-right:10%;
}

.verticalLine{
 background:black;
 width: 0px;
 height: 10%; 
}
```

```html
    <section id="section1">
        <div id="artworkArticlesLeft">
            <article id="artworkArticle1">
                <header>
                    <h1>Art Work</h1>
                </header>
                <p>Welcome to the main gallery</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div id="artworkArticlesRight">
          <div class="verticalLine">
            <article id="artworkArticle2">
                <p>Welcome to the main gallery</p>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Why have you not given a value to `border-left:`?

Comment: `border-left: 1px solid black` || `border-right: 2px dashed red` || another variation

Comment: Thanks it worked, i tried before but I must of did something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a line by using `border` property on a container with an article. Use either `border-right: 1px solid black` on first container (`artworkArticlesLeft`) or `border-left: 1px solid black` on second container (`artworkArticlesLeft`).

With your current styling this might not look so great as there are some positioning issues with second container (it's width is 100% of page - see in browser's element inspector). You might want to consider adjusting positioning of the components or using `display: flexbox`.

Comment: could you help me make the flexbox, I tried doing it and on the right side of the page there is this big indent making the second flexbox really small

Comment: You should use something like this:
- for `section1`:     `display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;`
-for `artworkArticlesLeft`: `flex: 3` 
-for `artworkArticlesRight`: `flex: 2`

But remember to remove your previous styling so it wont interfere.
Flexbox rules are greatly explained here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

To get a div to show up, you need to have at least 1px in width. Also, color in CSS refers usually to text color. You can use `background-color` or just `background` instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/kmd6d9n4/

Comment: I have a background color on the page and when i sent background color for the line it doesnt show and stays under the page background color, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You kept your width as 0px. Increase it to 1px.